# ListView - Can you set DataKeyNames when binding to a simple scalar array?

Tags: asp.net

I have a case that keeps coming up where I'm using a ListView or similar control with a simple array such as string[].

Is there a way to use the DataKeyNames property when you are binding to simple collections?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use DataKeys directly against the simple collection if possible -- without using a wrapper class or more complex collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with Linq:

```
string [] files = ...;

var list = from f in files
    select new { Letter = f };

// anonymous type created with member called Letter

lv.DataKeyNames = "Letter";
lv.DataSource = list;
lv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Generic List with objects object.  The example below is C# 3.0.  Say you want a list of letters:

```
public class LettersInfo
{
    public String Letter { get; set; }
}
```

then make a list:

```
List<LettersInfo> list = new List<LettersInfo>();
list.add(new LettersInfo{ Letter = "A" });
list.add(new LettersInfo{ Letter = "B" });
list.add(new LettersInfo{ Letter = "C" });
```

then bind it to the listview

```
lv.DataKeyNames = "Letter";
lv.DataSource = list;
lv.DataBind();
```